# Is "had" correct in "As you had not joined"?

Tags: past-tense, past-perfect, subjunctives

Is the following sentence correct?

> "As you **had** not joined our organization on 26 April 2017 as advised in
>   our letter of 30 March 2017, our Offer of Appointment is withdrawn"

Comment: Almost, but it should be "As you had not joined our organization *by*… "

Answer (score 0):

It is correct as written, but awkwardly written in a legalese kind of way.
While it does pass most grammar checks, I would probably add in a semicolon for emphasis and break-up:

"As you had not joined our organization on 26 April 2017; as advised in our letter of 30 March 2017, our Offer of Appointment is withdrawn" It could use a grammatical

Comment: I would change the semicolon to a comma; you use semicolons if you want to include two separate, but linked main clauses in the same sentence (like this!). The part after the semicolon and before the comma is a subordinate clause, which adds extra information to the main clause (like this!). In the case of a subordinate clause, commas should be used to mark it as separate from the main clause.

Comment: @SteveES I think it's all a matter of writing style and the inflection we want to deliver. I read this as being a 'snippy' remark and would want the long pause in there to emphasize the "if you did what we told you to" clause

Comment: Semicolons have a specific use, grammatically, and that is to separate two linked, independent clauses (or as a list separator when a comma is not appropriate); it is not just a long comma. The bit before the semicolon is not an independent clause, so using a semicolon there is grammatically incorrect.

Comment: An advice was made before the joining an organization was ignored, so why has the past perfect tense been used in the first part of the sentence and past simple - in the second part but not vice versa?